# I have 2 views in mvc, LoadBooks, RequirementBooks

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

In LoadBooks i have a javascript function getbooks() function.
Now I want to call that getbooks() function from RequirementBooks view, how can i do that

Comment: If getbooks is a common method, you can place it in a js and include that js on layout view. this way both the views will have this method available and your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .js file and refer it. Then, you can use in both views.